# How to add array values in Claims of IdToken in Cognito using claimsToAddOrOverride

Tags: json, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am using [Pre Token Generation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-lambda-trigger-syntax-pre-token-generation.html) to update the claims of IdToken.

I am successfully able to update claim using single key:value pair. 
Below is the sample example of that.

```
event["response"] = {"claimsOverrideDetails":{"claimsToAddOrOverride":{"scope": "test.debug"}}}
```

But when i am trying to add array of string inside that, it giving me **internal server error** (Response from AWS Cognito)

Ex:

```
event["response"] = {"claimsOverrideDetails":{"claimsToAddOrOverride":{"scope": ["test1","test2]}}}
```

> It is working fine using 'Test' option of lambda function.

If i am using **groupsToOverride** then it is overriding the **cognito:groups** claim.

Any help?

Comment: There's a AWS Forums post about this too (also unanswered at this time): https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=835981&#835981

Comment: ^ link now dead sadly.

Answer (score 11):

I think this must be a bug with Cognito and unfortunately will require a workaround until it's resolved.

It's not ideal I know, but I've worked around this issue by using a delimited string which I then parse to an array when I receive the token.

Lambda:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    event.response = {
        "claimsOverrideDetails": {
            "claimsToAddOrOverride": {
                "scope": "test1|test2"
            }
        }
    };

    // Return to Amazon Cognito
    callback(null, event);
};
```

Client:

```
const token = jwt.decode(id_token);
const scopes = token.scope.split('|');
```

Comment: Yes probably. Right now i am also using the same way, I have used `,` as delimited string :)

Comment: this is still a bug 2y later - seems using a string and then parsing the claim is the workaround for now.

Comment: or just stringify the array :)

Answer (score 2):

As annoying as it is, this is behaving as documented here.

The `response.claimsOverrideDetails.claimsToAddOrOverride` where you correctly are adding the claims you want added to the jwt takes a StringMap type, which is an object with all key value pairs having all values being strings.

This is in spite of the fact that some of the claims provided by AWS and passed into the PreTokenGeneration lambda are not strings, such as `auth_time` which is a number.

I find this particuarly annoying when I want to add a 'isRegistrationComplete' boolean to the jwt (which is used to force display of the pages to collect final registration details). I need to pass it in as:

```js
{
  isRegistrationComplete: "true"
}
```

or

```js
{
  isRegistrationComplete: "false"
}
```

Hence for your array, you must encode it as a string first.

You can do this for any object (including your array) using `JSON.stringify()` in the lambda code, and `JSON.parse()` code in your client.

You can find this documented on [this page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html) (find the text: `"claimsToAddOrOverride": {"string": "string"},`)

Comment: Yeah. seems like a fine workaround to use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, no need for over complicated custom delimited mapping required this way.

Answer (score 0):

The name **scope** have special meaning in a JWT, libraries expect this to be a list in string form separated by space. So the scopes test1 and test2 would become "test1 test2".

I would recommend using space as separator and not any other format. If you prefer another format just give your field a different name - like group.

```
{
  "iss": "https://authorization-server.example.com/",
  "sub": " 5ba552d67",
  "aud":   "https://rs.example.com/",
  "exp": 1544645174,
  "client_id": "s6BhdRkqt3_",
  "scope": "openid profile reademail"
}
```