# PreTokenGeneration Unrecognizable lambda output

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to add an account attribute in the identity token but it gives me problems when I run it from my web application.

I've been testing the lambda with the test event and it works correctly, I don't know what the problem may be, I already tried changing the response to callback and context, and they don't work either.

I am mounting this trigger with serverless framework, I have another PostConfirmation trigger with exactly the same settings and it works properly. The one that is giving me trouble is the PreTokenGeneration.

I am attaching the code I am using in my function:

```
module.exports.execute = async (event, context) => {
  const { sub } = event.request.userAttributes;

  const getUserQuery = {
    TableName: `my-table`,
    Key: { id: sub }
  };

  try {
    const data = await dynamoDb.get(getUserQuery).promise();
    console.log("DEBUG: query data", data);
    const account = data.Item.accounts.find(
      account => account.id === data.Item.currentAccountId
    );

    event.response = {
      claimsOverrideDetails: {
        claimsToAddOrOverride: {
          account: account
        }
      }
    };

    console.log("OUTPUT: ", event);
    return event;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("ERROR:", error);
    throw Error(
      JSON.stringify({
        error: error.message
      })
    );
  }
};
```

And this is the error it gives me in my web application

```
{"__type":"InvalidLambdaResponseException","message":"Unrecognizable lambda output"}
```

What could I be doing wrong? I don't know where else to look, the lambda logs tell me that everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

`account` appears to be an object; currently, arrays and objects cannot be used with claimsToAddOrOverride, only string key-value pairs.

Try flattening the structure, either through stringify, or by using multiple keys e.g.

```
claimsOverrideDetails: {
  claimsToAddOrOverride: {
    accountId: account.id,
    accountName: account.name
    ...
  }
}
```

Related: [How to add array values in Claims of IdToken in Cognito using claimsToAddOrOverride](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556221)